# C# в VSCode не работает .NET

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Устанавливал .NET 2.1 SDK 
VSCode для него дополнения C# 
даже в терминале работает 
dotnet new console
НО когда захожу в VSCode у меня нету ни дебаггинга для шарпа 
не работает Intellisense. Как тектовый редактор с подсветкой кода включается.
Покопался в настройках VSCode тоже ничего интересного не нашел.
КАК включить Фреймворк для него и Ядро .NET ?

Comment: [Working with C#](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/csharp), [Using .NET Core in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/dotnet)

Comment: Дебаггинг не работает в 32-х разрядной ос (расширение Omnisharp), может быть это ваша проблема